# Remove code duplication for virtual class members in C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, refactoring, protected, code-duplication

I have got myself into a strange issue now. Ill write a really simplified version of the same.

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual int func1()=0;
  virtual int func2()=0;
protected:
  int n;
};

class der1: public Base
{
  // implements the virtual functions of the base and uses the protected data 
  // members of the base.
};

class der2: public Base
{
  // implements the virtual functions of the base and uses the protected data 
  // members of the base.
}
```

Now the problem.... both `der1` and `der2` implements the virtual functions of base pretty much the same way. But some other classes (`der3`, `der4`) has their own implementations. But still need to inherit from base.
How do i refactor the code to remove the code duplication in an oop manner?

Comment: You can provide commonly used code in the base class as protected member functions.

Comment: You can derive `Der1` and `Der2` from `Base12` that itself derives from `Base`.

Comment: as I said, only two classes have the code in common and again some other classes have a different set of common code. So, there is no common code that caters all these 4 classes. Similarly, in future there might be some more classes that inherit this base class. Hence, don't really want to bother the base class.

Comment: _@lifeOfPi_ Then probably @Evg's proposal is the way to go.

Comment: i tried @Evg's solution and faced the problem that Base12 has to now implement these pure virtual functions of Base and again, der1 and der2 also has to implement the same ... is there a better way?

Comment: @lifeOfPi With `Base12` you should not implement the pure virtual functions, but do what I said in the beginning.

Comment: You can keep `Base12` abstract as well, there shouldn't be need to instantiate those... Anyway, I'd be more inclined to πάντα ῥεῖ solution - If there's something common, define it in `Base`, then override this implementation in `Der3` and `Der4`. No need for yet another layer of abstraction.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the problem is if I derive from base, ill have to provide a definition of those pure virtual functions, else I can't create a concrete class. Do you want to say that let this intermediate class be an abstract and not a concrete?

Comment: @lifeOfPi _" if I derive from base, ill have to provide a definition of those pure virtual functions"_ that's wrong. You can leave any intermediate layer of another base class abstract, unless you need to instantiate it directly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: do you mind sharing a simple code snippet where the intermediate class has the common code for der1 and der2.... and yet being an abstract class?

Comment: _@lifeOfPi_ I did now. But IMO @Yksisarvinen is right. If you have commonly used stuff you should place it in the original base class. This makes extending the class hierarchy easier later on.

Comment: This whole question depends entirely on what "pretty much the same way" means, exactly. You should have provided a concrete example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution using an intermediate layer of another abstract base class:

```
class Base12 : public Base {
protected: 
    int commonFuncStuffA() {
       // Commonly used stuff 
    }

    int commonFuncStuffB() {
    }
};

class der1: public Base12
{
public:
    virtual int func1() {
        n = commonFuncStuffA();
    }
    virtual int func2() {
        n = somethingElse;
    }
};

class der2: public Base12
{
public:
    virtual int func1() {
        n = commonFuncStuffA();
    }
    virtual int func2() {
        n = commonFuncStuffB();
    }
};
```

---

What I'd do for real production code design looks a bit different though.

1. Declare an interface for the pure virtual functions

   ```
   struct IMyInterface {
       virtual int func1() = 0;
       virtual int func2() = 0;
       virtual ~IMyInterface {}
   };
   ```
2. Provide a abstract base class with the commonly used data members and functions

   ```
   class BaseImpl : public IMyInterface {
   protected: 
       int n;
       int commonFuncStuffA() {
           // Commonly used stuff 
       }

       int commonFuncStuffB() {
           // Commonly used stuff 
       }
   };
   ```
3. Provide implementations of the interface in the finally derived classes

   ```
   class der1: public BaseImpl {
   public:
       virtual int func1() {
           n = commonFuncStuffA();
       }
       virtual int func2() {
           n = somethingElse;
       }
   };


   class der2: public BaseImpl {
   public:
       virtual int func1() {
           n = commonFuncStuffA();
       }
       virtual int func2() {
           n = commonFuncStuffB();
       }
   };

   class der3: public IMyInterface {
   public:
       virtual int func1() {
           // Some completely different implementation of the interface
       }
       virtual int func2() {
           // Some completely different implementation of the interface
       }
   };

   class der4: public IMyInterface {
   public:
       virtual int func1() {
           // Some completely different implementation of the interface
       }
       virtual int func2() {
           // Some completely different implementation of the interface
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: haha,,, that's a typo...  but it solves my problem.... thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

You may consider using your most common implementation in the `Base` class. The main feature or drawback of this method is that the base class would no longer be abstract.  If this is a problem, go to option 2.

Maybe you can even cope with differences in the derived classes by using the **[template method pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html)** to extract the differences in protected virtual functions invoked by the template method.

In anyway, for derived classes that need a completely different appoach, you'd just override the the Base class' method.

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual int func1();
  virtual int func2()=0;
protected:
  virtual void f1_specific_part1()=0;
  virtual void f1_specific_part2()=0; 
  int n;
};
int Base::func1() { // common skeleton of the algorithm
     ...  
     f1_specific_part1(); 
     ... 
     f1_specific_part2(); 
     ...
}     

class Der1: public Base
{ 
protected:
 void f1_specific_part1() override;  // Implements the specific variation
 virtual void f1_specific_part2() override;       
};
```

### Option 2

You may consider to factorize the common code of the derived classes into a protected method of the `Base` class.

The override of the pure virtual function would then just call the base class protected common function (for `der1` and `der2`) or just use their own implementation that is completely different (for `der3` and `der4`).

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual int func1()=0;
  virtual int func2()=0;
protected:
  int common_part1_funct1(); // implements some common parts 
  int common_part2_funct1();
  int n;
};

class Der1: public Base
{
...
  int func1() override { 
     common_part1_funct1();
     ...
     common_part2_funct1(); 
     ... 
  }
};
```

### Option 3 ?

**Important remark:** My answer assumes that there are many commonalities between most of the derived classes.  However if you have only a small subset of derived classes that share some commonalities, then the answer of [Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg) would be would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with `Base12` is:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int func1() = 0;
    virtual int func2() = 0;
};

struct Base12 : Base {
protected:
    int func12();
};

struct Der1: public Base12 {
    virtual int func1() {
        return func12();
    virtual int func2() {
        return func12();
};

struct Der2: public Base12 {
    virtual int func1() {
        return func12();
    virtual int func2() {
        return func12();
};
```